# Dynamic selecting of children records

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I  have a table for comments where I can add records in n levels, it means that I can have a comment that it is in the nth level of reply of a comment.

My problem is that how can I dynamically select n levels of comment using linq?

For example I want comments reply for 5th level or 2nd or nth.

Here is my table

```
public partial class {

public Comment()
{
    this.Comments1 = new HashSet<Comment>();
}

public int CommentId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments1 { get; set; }
public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
}
```

till now i use linq and call this function in sql-server to get all the children :

```
[DbFunction("Ents", "cmTree")]
   public virtual IQueryable<ContentComment> cmTree(string topLevelComments)
   {
       var topLevelCommentsParameter = topLevelComments != null ?
           new ObjectParameter("topLevelComments", topLevelComments) :
           new ObjectParameter("topLevelComments", typeof(string));

       return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<ContentComment>("[Entities].[cmTree](@topLevelComments)", topLevelCommentsParameter);
   }
```

an then in sql-server:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[cmTree] 
(
-- Table types seems goods here.
-- but in application-level, linq to sql technology dose not support table types.
-- TupleValue type can user for future use.
   @topLevelComments NVARCHAR(max)

)
RETURNS @resultTable TABLE (
[Id] [bigint] primary KEY NOT NULL,
[AuthorUserId] [int] NULL,
[AuthorName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[AuthorEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[AuthorUrl] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
[AuthorIp] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[InsertDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[BodyContent] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[IsApproved] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsAlertable] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ContentId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ParentCommentId] [bigint] NULL,
[VerifierUserID] [int] NULL,
[VerifyDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastModifierUserId] [int] NULL,
[LastModifiedDateTime] [datetime] NULL
)

AS
BEGIN
with CommentTableExpression As (

-- Anchor entities
select rC.Id, rc.AuthorUserId, rc.AuthorName, rc.[AuthorEmail], rc.[AuthorUrl], rc.[AuthorIp], rc.[InsertDateTime], rc.[BodyContent], rc.[IsApproved], rc.[IsAlertable], rc.[ContentId], rc.[ParentCommentId], rc.[VerifierUserID], rc.[VerifyDateTime], rc.[Status], rc.[LastModifierUserId], rc.[LastModifiedDateTime] 
from dbo.ContentComments as rC
WHERE rc.ParentCommentId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@topLevelComments))

union all

-- Recursive query execution
select child.Id, child.AuthorUserId, child.AuthorName, child.[AuthorEmail], child.[AuthorUrl], child.[AuthorIp], child.[InsertDateTime], child.[BodyContent], child.[IsApproved], child.[IsAlertable], child.[ContentId], child.[ParentCommentId], child.[VerifierUserID], child.[VerifyDateTime], child.[Status], child.[LastModifierUserId], child.[LastModifiedDateTime]

from dbo.ContentComments as child
inner join CommentTableExpression as t_Comment
on child.ParentCommentId = t_Comment.Id
where child.ParentCommentId is not NULL) -- commente contet=nt budan barasi shavad.

INSERT @resultTable Select * from CommentTableExpression

RETURN 
END
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey i uppdated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to manage one more field in the table called "ChildLevel" and add reply level in that field.

But if you want to use same structure and want to manage then below linq will get 5th level children

```
var rec = dt.Comments().Where(t => t.Comment1 != null 
              && t.Comment1.Comment1 != null 
              && t.Comment1.Comment1.Comment1 != null 
              && t.Comment1.Comment1.Comment1.Comment1 != null );
```

Comment: Thanks But this is a Static way To achieve this . i want to dynamicly generate Childrens. can i dynamicly Generate Linq Expression?

Comment: for dynamically get childrens you have to use nested loop (may be by recursive function) and get all childrens like while getting  1st level check if it has 2nd level & in 2nd level check if it has 3rd level.. etc.

Comment: Thank you I give it a Try and See what will happen